# Trouble with MYSQL update column for one selection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting this to update when needed. This is an optout script intended to updated the selected email row with the value of 1 in the removed column. I can't seem to get it to update and I'm thinking its an issue with my sql. Any help in understanding this is much appreciated. 
As a note:
I'm making it to Sorry there seems to be an issue with.........

Here is the script.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['e'])) {

    include_once "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

    $email = $_GET['e'];

    $sql_delete = mysql_query("UPDATE test WHERE email='$email' SET removed = '1'");

    if (!$sql_delete) {
        echo "Sorry there seems to be and issue when trying to remove your listing. Please email Admin directly using this email address: chris@.com";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry to see you go! You will not receive our newsletter ever again unless you relist. To gain access to our newsletter again simply let us know by email at chris@.com";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting when you `die(mysql_error())` ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql_delete = mysql_query("UPDATE test SET removed = '1' WHERE email='$email'");
```

The problem is your syntax, have a look at the mysql `update` syntax, where the `where` clause should go and where `set` should go http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html.

You would have seen this problem had you used proper error handling, like follows:

```
$sql_delete = mysql_query("UPDATE test SET removed = '1' WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Have a look at `mysql_real_escape_string` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php, to prevent SQL injection.  Example:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$sql_delete = mysql_query("UPDATE test SET removed = '1' WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also note that `mysql_` extension are deprecated, you want to start using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: You got it brotha. Thanks for helping out. So the order of these must be exact, is this correct?

Comment: @Chris yes there is a order to it

Comment: @Chris what have to tried to debug code ? have you tried general debugging process ? and what exactly error are getting ?

Comment: Y U NO SQL injection warning .. ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, that was going to be next.  Thanks for reminding though.

Comment: @vinodadhikary thanks for the heads up..You know I just used that this morning then forgot to use that here. Still learning..thanks for the help. What are your thoughts on sql injection prevention here?

Comment: @Chris, just added a statement in my answer.  Sorry forgot to add the word Update.  Please read on `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 1):

Use `SET` before your `WHERE` clause.

```sql
UPDATE test 
SET removed = '1'
WHERE email = '$email'
```

Answer (score 1):

The update syntax is

```
UPDATE
    table
SET
    column = value
WHERE
    condition = met
```

On another note, I see you're using a very unsafe method of dynamic entries (`$_GET`) and `Mysql_*` function are deprecated in new version of php `>=  5.5`. I'd highly recommend researching PDO for the use of bind variables otherwise you can easily get "hacked" if

```
$_GET['e'] = "fake' OR '1'='1" // known as sql injection
```

**Good Read**

- [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1723893)

Comment: is the above escape string valuable in this situation?

Comment: @Chris he is showing you that he can easily hack your website because you have no protection against SQL Injection, see my answer, and that you should migrate to MySQLi or PDO as mysql_ is deprectated and may in future version be removed.

Comment: @Prix no I mean the mysql_real_escape_string not the "fake' or ect.

Comment: @Chris there is a huge difference, using it, it will escape any dangerous characters while without it won't see an example on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, your [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) is incorrect. This is the correct form:

```
UPDATE test
SET removed = '1'
WHERE email = '$email'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
mysql_query("UPDATE test SET removed = '1' WHERE email='$email'");
```

But please notice that this extension is deprecated. 
Use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

the solution in both extensions are as follows.

**MySQLi:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(GDB_HOST, GDB_USERNAME, GDB_PASSWORD, GDB_NAME);
$cmd = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE test SET removed = '1' WHERE email= ? ");
$cmd->bind_param('s', $email);
$cmd->execute();
```

**PDO**

```
$dbh = Database::connect();
$query = "UPDATE test SET removed = '1' WHERE email= ? ";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute(array($email));
```

One of the big importances of using one of these 2 extensions is the fact that you avoid any attempt of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)